# Sharing babelified ECMAScript modules between Node and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I’m using Babel to compile my JavaScript code and I have separate configs for webpack (base) and Node (override):

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/env',
            {
                modules: false,
                useBuiltIns: 'usage',
            },
        ],
        '@babel/react',
        '@babel/flow',
    ],
    overrides: [
        {
            include: ['src/scripts'],
            presets: [
                [
                    '@babel/env',
                    {
                        modules: 'commonjs',
                        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                        targets: {
                            node: '6',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            ],
        },
    ],
};
```

So `scripts` is my Node code, the rest is client-side (webpack). I can't import anything inside `scripts` folder, from a module in any other folder.

If I use a default export:

```
export default function fn() {}
```

And import it like this:

```
import fn from '../scripts/fn'
```

I see this error:

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'fn') was not found in '../scripts/fn'
```

If I use a named export:

```
export function fn() {}
```

And import it like this:

```
import {fn} from '../scripts/fn'
```

I see this error:

```
"'../scripts/fn' does not contain an export named 'fn'.
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error, when running or compiling which part? Also, in which part do you try to import the script?

Comment: It must be from webpack when I try to run it:

“Compiled with warnings
./lib/client/test.js 23:12-18
"export 'default' (imported as 'fn') was not found in '../scripts/fn'”

Babel works fine (I use a command line tool).

Comment: Why does your client script try to include serverside parts?

Comment: Because I want to share code that make sense on client and server, instead of duplicating it, as mentioned in the question title.

Comment: You should share the sources, not the babelified outputs that use different module systems.

Comment: Could you be more specific how exactly I should do that?